# Tracking team record by game in df

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to add a column that will keep track of each teams record game by game. I have a season column, which labels each season and post season for the last few years.

```
array(['2012-13', '2013-14', '2014-15', '2015 Post', '2015-16',
       '2016 Post', '2016-17', '2017 Post', '2013 Post', '2014 Post'], dtype=object)
```

Should I use groupby to separate each seasons first or is that not necessary. I tried searching everywhere for a similar question and found nothing so not really sure how to even approach this problem. Cheers!

```
                 Date             Visitor  V_PTS                  Home  H_PTS  \
0 2012-10-30 19:00:00  Washington Wizards     84   Cleveland Cavaliers     94   
1 2012-10-30 19:30:00    Dallas Mavericks     99    Los Angeles Lakers     91   
2 2012-10-30 20:00:00      Boston Celtics    107            Miami Heat    120   
3 2012-10-31 19:00:00    Dallas Mavericks     94             Utah Jazz    113   
4 2012-10-31 19:00:00   San Antonio Spurs     99  New Orleans Pelicans     95   

   Attendance                    Arena                 Location  Capacity  \
0       20562      Quicken Loans Arena          Cleveland, Ohio     20562   
1       18997           Staples Center  Los Angeles, California     18997   
2       20296  American Airlines Arena           Miami, Florida     19600   
3       17634  Vivint Smart Home Arena     Salt Lake City, Utah     18303   
4       15358     Smoothie King Center   New Orleans, Louisiana     16867   

  Yr Arena Opened   Season  H_Wins  H_Losses  V_Wins  V_Losses  
0            1994  2012-13       0         0       0         0  
1            1992  2012-13       0         0       0         0  
2            1999  2012-13       0         0       0         0  
3            1991  2012-13       0         0       0         0  
4            1999  2012-13       0         0       0         0
```

I know this isn't the most pythonic way, but so far I can characterize it as a win or a loss using this code

```
nba['Wins'] = np.where(nba['H_PTS']>nba['V_PTS'], 1, 0)
nba['Losses'] = np.where(nba['H_PTS']<nba['V_PTS'], 1, 0)
```

Is there a way to get it to add onto itself based on column in same season label?

Comment: Can you clarify what the output should look like for your sample data?  Do you want it for Visiting teams only or for Home teams as well?

Comment: Both. For instance, the first games listed all teams will be 0-0. The next game Cleveland appears in I'd like it to show they are 1-0 and if they win that game then 2-0 for the next game and so on. Also making sure that when the Season changes it resets back to 0-0.

Comment: Thanks - I'm still a unclear on what the output should look like, though.  It sounds like you don't just want the total wins and losses, but a running count.  Can you add the desired output to the post itself?

Comment: Ok updated it. Yes a running total is what I want not just a total sum. Basically that row will always only show what their record was on the date the game was played if that makes sense.

Comment: I think I understand now.  In the future, try to construct your expected output so it (1) is distinct from the input and (2) actually shows the behavior you want - right now it's part of the input dataframe, and none of the summing behavior you want is in there.

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate your help and feedback.

Comment: Glad to help, writing up answer now (hint: use `groupby()` and `cumsum()`)

Comment: Taking a little more time than I expected, but will have an answer by tomorrow.  Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the help I really appreciate it! Makes me feel a little better about being stuck on it myself haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be more complicated than it looks.  There are definitely ways to simplify the solution I've found, but I'm going to lay it out step by step so it's clear what's going on.

But first it's worth taking a moment to ask why this is tricky.  It looks like a simple `groupby()` problem, using `.cumsum()` to add up the wins and losses.  And if you just wanted to get the results for visiting teams, it would be.  But your problem is you want to get wins for *teams, period*, whether or not they're visiting or at home.

To do that, I suggest breaking the problem into several steps (always a useful thing to do when you've got some problematic code).

**Main answer**

First, split your data into two dataframes, one for visiting teams and the other for home teams:

```
vdf = nba.set_index(['Season', 'Date', 'Visitor'])
vdf['win'] = np.where(vdf['H_PTS'] < vdf['V_PTS'], 1, 0)
vdf.index.names = ['Season', 'Date', 'Team']

hdf = nba.set_index(['Season', 'Date', 'Home'])
hdf['win'] = np.where(hdf['H_PTS'] > hdf['V_PTS'], 1, 0)
hdf.index.names = ['Season', 'Date', 'Team']
```

Once split, we're doing two things to each dataframe.  First, we're creating a `win` column using `np.where()` (perfectly pythonic, by the way.  I'd say just use the boolean, but that doesn't play nicely with `.cumsum()`).  Second, we rename the index so instead of visitors and home teams, we're just talking about teams.  This is important, because now we're going to merge these dataframes into one again:

```
df = pd.concat([vdf, hdf])
df['loss'] = 1 - df.win
df = df.sort_index(level=['Date'])
gr = df.groupby(level=['Season', 'Team'])
```

We can calculate a `loss` for a team as a simple inverse of the `win`s.  Then we sort by the `Date` - since no team can play two games at the same time, this should be fine.  Then we'll group by `Season` and `Team`, since that's the group over which you want to count results.

Now it's pretty simple to cumulatively sum the wins and losses:

```
df['wins'] = gr.win.apply(lambda g: g.shift().cumsum().fillna(0))
df['losses'] = gr.loss.apply(lambda g: g.shift().cumsum().fillna(0))
```

If you wanted to get the results including the current game, you could just use `.cumsum()`.  But since you want the results as of the prior game, we need to use `.shift()`, and then fill in the (now empty) first row with 0.

But now we've got a problem: the home and visitor teams are on different rows!  To fix this, we split them up into separate dataframes again and rename the columns to make it clear whether we're talking about visitor or home records.

```
vdf = df.dropna(subset=['Home'])[['wins', 'losses']].rename(columns=lambda c: 'V_' + c)
hdf = df.dropna(subset=['Visitor'])[['wins', 'losses']].rename(columns=lambda c: 'H_' + c)
```

The last real step is merging back into the main dataframe based on the `Visitor` and `Home` team names.

```
nba = nba.merge(vdf.astype(int), left_on=['Season', 'Date', 'Visitor'], right_index=True)
nba = nba.merge(hdf.astype(int), left_on=['Season', 'Date', 'Home'], right_index=True)
```

Finally, we can (optionally) produce the kind of `W-L` format you mention in the comments:

```
nba['V_winloss'] = nba['V_wins'].astype(str) + '-' + nba['V_losses'].astype(str)
nba['H_winloss'] = nba['H_wins'].astype(str) + '-' + nba['H_losses'].astype(str)
```

Done!  Simplifying it further (which can definitely be done) is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

**All the code in one place:**

```
vdf = nba.set_index(['Season', 'Date', 'Visitor'])
vdf['win'] = np.where(vdf['H_PTS'] < vdf['V_PTS'], 1, 0)
vdf.index.names = ['Season', 'Date', 'Team']

hdf = nba.set_index(['Season', 'Date', 'Home'])
hdf['win'] = np.where(hdf['H_PTS'] > hdf['V_PTS'], 1, 0)
hdf.index.names = ['Season', 'Date', 'Team']

df = pd.concat([vdf, hdf])
df['loss'] = 1 - df.win
df['location'] = np.where(pd.notnull(df['Home']), 'h', 'v')
df = df.sort_index(level=['Date'])
gr = df.groupby(level=['Season', 'Team'])

df['wins'] = gr.win.apply(lambda g: g.shift().cumsum().fillna(0))
df['losses'] = gr.loss.apply(lambda g: g.shift().cumsum().fillna(0))

vdf = df.dropna(subset=['Home'])[['wins', 'losses']].rename(columns=lambda c: 'V_' + c)
hdf = df.dropna(subset=['Visitor'])[['wins', 'losses']].rename(columns=lambda c: 'H_' + c)

nba = nba.merge(vdf.astype(int), left_on=['Season', 'Date', 'Visitor'], right_index=True)
nba = nba.merge(hdf.astype(int), left_on=['Season', 'Date', 'Home'], right_index=True)

nba['V_winloss'] = nba['V_wins'].astype(str) + '-' + nba['V_losses'].astype(str)
nba['H_winloss'] = nba['H_wins'].astype(str) + '-' + nba['H_losses'].astype(str)
```

---

**An Example (and some advice)**

Whenever you've got a question, try to construct both a sample of your desired input and of your desired output, formatted in such a way that answerers can copy-paste it directly into their code.   This sample should demonstrate the key requirements for your task.  In your case, this would probably include a team that plays both a home game and an away game, and multiple seasons.  This is a useful exercise even before you ask a question - building a test bed with basic cases makes it easy to check if the code you're writing it working as intended.

I've made a sample dataframe that includes these features.  Note that I've removed columns which don't matter for the problem at hand.

```
>>> nba

   Season  Date Visitor Home  V_PTS  H_PTS
0       1     1       A    E      1      2
1       1     2       B    E      1      0
2       1     3       C    E      1      2
3       1     4       D    E      1      0
4       1     5       E    A      1      2
5       1     6       E    B      1      0
6       1     7       E    C      1      2
7       1     8       E    D      1      0
8       2     9       A    E      1      2
```

After you calculate the wins and losses (`df['losses'] = ...`), you should check to see that team results are accumulating correctly:

```
>>> print df[['wins', 'losses']].sort_index(level=['Team', 'Date']).astype(int)

                  wins  losses
Season Date Team
1      1    A        0       0
       5    A        0       1
2      9    A        0       0
1      2    B        0       0
       6    B        1       0
       3    C        0       0
       7    C        0       1
       4    D        0       0
       8    D        1       0
       1    E        0       0
       2    E        1       0
       3    E        1       1
       4    E        2       1
       5    E        2       2
       6    E        2       3
       7    E        3       3
       8    E        3       4
2      9    E        0       0
```

Then by the end, you'll get this:

```
   Season  Date Visitor Home  V_PTS  H_PTS  V_wins  V_losses  H_wins  \
0       1     1       A    E      1      2       0         0       0
1       1     2       B    E      1      0       0         0       1
2       1     3       C    E      1      2       0         0       1
3       1     4       D    E      1      0       0         0       2
4       1     5       E    A      1      2       2         2       0
5       1     6       E    B      1      0       2         3       1
6       1     7       E    C      1      2       3         3       0
7       1     8       E    D      1      0       3         4       1
8       2     9       A    E      1      2       0         0       0

   H_losses V_winloss H_winloss
0         0       0-0       0-0
1         0       0-0       1-0
2         1       0-0       1-1
3         1       0-0       2-1
4         1       2-2       0-1
5         0       2-3       1-0
6         1       3-3       0-1
7         0       3-4       1-0
8         0       0-0       0-0
```

You can look it over to make sure it matches what you want.

Comment: Amazing!! Don't think I ever would have got there without you. Great description and walk through your process. I'll be sure to reread multiple times to get a great grasp of the concepts. Appreciate your feedback for future posts as well. Thank you so much again!!

Comment: I know how frustrating it can be to look at a "simple" problem and not be able to solve it.  I'm sure you will come up with a much simpler way of handling it in the future, and hopefully post a better answer here someday.  Until then, glad to have helped!